# Como fazer um aplicativo web localhost tipo configurador de modem?

Tags: c#, aplicação-web, windows-service

Olá. Sou desenvolvedor C# e preciso fazer um aplicativo de configuração de um Serviço Windows. Pensei em algo parecido com aqueles aplicativos de configuração de modem de internet que rodam diretamente no Browser. Existe uma forma de rodar um aplicativo destes, em uma máquina local sem a necessidade de instalar o IIS nesta máquina? Qual a melhor abordagem para resolver esse problema? Alguma documentação sobre o assunto já é útil. Obrigado.

Comment: O próprio modem tem um servidor de página. Não precisa ser um IIS, mas você precisa fazer um mini-servidor de páginas próprio para acessar pelo browser. Com C# você tem tudo praticamente pronto para fazer esse mini-servidor, é mais questão de entender a linguagem e o protocolo HTTP.

Comment: Não analisei a qualidade do código, mas numa rápida pesquisa por WebServer C# já me veio isso como um dos primeiros resultados: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1505/Create-your-own-Web-Server-using-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc pode usar classe .net `HttpListener`. Documentacao e exemplo [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Procura mais exemplos no internet, tem monte, como esse no [github](https://gist.github.com/aksakalli/9191056).

Se vc precisar de uma funcionalidade mas elaborada, talvez uma opcao seria usar `lighhttpd` ou mongoose.

Comment: Por favor poste exemplos, pois links podem ficar off e aqui ficar com referências vazias. Postando exemplos, você auxilia outras pessoas em qualquer tempo.